# to cut song with millisecond precision

Tags: ios, cmtime

I can cut a song in range start time to duration, bot are float.
But i get only seconds in final song.

```
CMTime sTime=CMTimeMake(startTime*1000, 1000);
CMTime eTime=CMTimeMake(duration*1000, 1000);

CMTimeRange editRange = CMTimeRangeMake(sTime,eTime);
[myMutableCompostion insertTimeRange:editRange ofAsset:sourceAsset atTime:myMutableCompostion.duration error:&editError];
```

Eg:
    `startime=50.0 duration=23.9`
song should be 23.9 seconds, but I get only 23 seconds.

Please help me to cut song with millisecond precision.

Comment: That's because [CMTime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMTime) is an integer (int64/int32). I don't know enough about an alternative to give you an answer, but this should explain why this is happening.